# Django - Add object in front of existing QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am building a `library` Django application where I have a `BooksView` to display all `Book`s written by a certain `Author`. Under certain conditions, I want a single `Book` to be displayed before all other books in the query set. This should happen when the id of the book appears in the URL, otherwise, all books should be listed in chronological order.

**books/urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [

    # Books displayed in chronological order
    path("<slug:author>/books", views.BooksView.as_view()),

    # Books displayed in chronological order
    # but first book is the one with id `book`
    path("<slug:author>/books/<int:book>", views.BooksView.as_view()),
]
```

**books/views.py**:

```
class BooksView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, author, book=None):

        author = get_object_or_404(Author, slug=author)
        books = author.author_books
        books = books.order_by("-pub_date")

        if book:
            book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=book)
            # TODO: add `book` in front of books QuerySet (and remove duplicated if any)

        serializer = BooksSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

How can I accomplish my **TODO**? How can I push an object in front of an existing query set?

Comment: Could you please check the schema that created in the database? Does it have unique index on your column? something like table(lower(col_name));

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't precisely answer your question but I think it would allow you to get the desired outcome:  don't worry about preserving the queryset and instead transform it into a list.

This isn't a thing you want to do for every queryset in your entire codebase especially if it's a queryset that you might later want to build upon and compose with other filters, excludes, etc.  But when you're about to render a page (like you are here) it is OK because you're about to cause the queryset to be evaluated anyhow.  You're causing it to happen perhaps microseconds sooner.

```
class BooksView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, author, book=None):

        author = get_object_or_404(Author, slug=author)
        books = list(author.author_books)

        if book:
            book = Book.objects.get(id=book)
            # TODO: add `book` in front of books QuerySet (and remove duplicated if any)
            books = [x for x in books if not x == book] # first remove if dup
            books.insert(0, book) # now insert at front

        serializer = BooksSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

#### EDIT 1

The BooksSerializer (which subclasses the BaseSerializer I suspect) is going to make a list anyhow as soon as you call it:

```
    def to_representation(self, data):
        """
        List of object instances -> List of dicts of primitive datatypes.
        """
        # Dealing with nested relationships, data can be a Manager,
        # so, first get a queryset from the Manager if needed
        iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data

        return [
            self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
        ]
```

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L663

#### EDIT 2

What about trying this instead?  By adding the `exclude` before the queryset is evaluated into a list you prevent the O(n) scan through the list to find and remove the "main" book that's supposed to be at the top.

```
class BooksView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, author, book=None):

        author = get_object_or_404(Author, slug=author)
        books = author.author_books

        if book:
            book = Book.objects.get(id=book)
            # TODO: add `book` in front of books QuerySet (and remove duplicated if any)
            # ensure the queryset doesn't include the "main" book
            books = books.exclude(book_id=book.id)
            # evaluate it into a list just like the BookSerializer will anyhow
            books = list(books)
            # now insert the "main" book at the front of the list 
            books.insert(0, book)

        serializer = BooksSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Evaluation the QuerySet just to do an insert is not a good idea

Comment: The evaluation of the queryset happens as soon as the serializer is called.  I can't see why performing that operation a tiny bit sooner is going to cause a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. However, it looks to me like it is very expensive. I was hoping for something closer to an O(1) algorithm (I might be wrong though)

Comment: Well rendering the queryset into json is going to be O(n) and this performs O(n) operations as well so it turns it into O(2*n) which to me doesn't seem to be a big deal. I think there's a way to make it less expensive though.

Comment: So far your second solution is the winner for me. I am waiting to see if better solutions come along otherwise I'll be accepting your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you're worried about real-world performance you might take a peek at django-debug-toolbar for webpages or insomnia/postman for REST APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **bitwise `|`** operator as

```
from django.http.response import Http404


class BooksView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, author, book=None):
        author = get_object_or_404(Author, slug=author)
        book_qs = author.author_books
        if book:
            single_book_qs = Book.objects.filter(id=book)
            if not single_book_qs.exists():
                raise Http404
            book_qs = single_book_qs | book_qs

        serializer = BooksSerializer(book_qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Please note that one caveat of this solution is that, if you use the **`order_by(...)`** method, the position will be changed according to the ORDER By expression.

### Update 1

Since you are using an `order_by(...)` expression, you must do something like this,

```
class BooksView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, author, book=None):
        author = get_object_or_404(Author, slug=author)
        book_qs = author.author_books.order_by("-pub_date")
        serialized_single_book = []
        if book:
            single_book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=book)
            book_qs.exclude(id=book) # to remove dups
            serialized_single_book = [BooksSerializer(single_book).data]

        serializer = BooksSerializer(book_qs, many=True)
        serialized_book_qs = serializer.data
        return Response([*serialized_single_book, *serialized_book_qs])
```

Comment: I apologize for this but I omitted a very important detail from the code in my question. I added a line that sorts what you called `book_qs` by the publication dates of the books. With that line, your code does not seem to work anymore.

Comment: @fredperk check the `Update-1`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, just use the union method in the `QuerySet` object, and exclude
the book we are trying to access from `books` queryset.

I did some minor changes to the code, but you don't need to do more than that, to accomplish what you need.

```
class BooksView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, author, book=None):
        author = get_object_or_404(Author, slug=author)
        books = author.author_books.all().order_by('-pub_date')

        if book:
            # I am assuming this line if for validating that the request is valid.
            # I've changed the query to also include author's slug,
            # so the request doesn't get books not related to the author.
            book_obj = get_object_or_404(Book, id=book, author__slug=author)

            # Just Query the same book, and union it with the books queryset,
            # excluding the current book in the book_obj
            books = Book.objects.filter(id=book_obj.id).union(books.exclude(id=book_obj.id))

        serializer = BooksSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: This is the way to go and should be the accepted answer IMO. One optimization you can make though is replace the `.union(books.exclude(id=book_obj.id))` by `.union(books)` as SQL `UNION` defaults to excluding duplicates https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#union

Comment: I tried this too, but union ordering is not predictable on Postgres at least. And yes, I flipped first / second of the union, excluded, didn't exclude, order inside the union - all of it.

Answer (score 0):

A little out of the box maybe, but if you want to keep it as queryset, then this is the solution. Please note that this solves the [X problem, not the Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The goal is to put one book first in the list, which can be achieved by insertion, but also by reordering based on an annotation.

```py
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, IntegerField
from rest_framework import generics

from . import models, serializers


class BooksPerAuthor(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.BookWithoutAuthor

    def get_queryset(self):
        book_pk = self.kwargs.get("book", 0)
        queryset = (
            models.Book.objects.filter(author__slug=self.kwargs["author"])
            .annotate(
                promoted=Case(
                    When(pk=book_pk, then=Value(1)),
                    default=Value(0),
                    output_field=IntegerField(),
                )
            )
            .order_by("-promoted", "-pub_date")
        )
        return queryset
```

This doesn't catch non-existing references - not a fan of returning 404 for list views and in case the promoted book is not in the collection, then there's no real harm done. Plenty of examples above to do the same thing with 404's at the (minor) cost of additional queries.